# Chromium semi freezing in a predictable way on very unclear reasons

Tags: vue.js, chromium, display, freeze

I have a Raspberry PI 3B+/raspbian running my NodeJS (node-red) backend application. My Raspberry is hosting a frontend application (VueJS) as well. I also have a 7" display connected. The purpose with the system is to display a map of 433 Mhz electrical switches in my home.

If I, for example, click on a switch on the display - the system should turn on/off the lamp and indicate the current state. This has been working flawless for months!
[image]
A picture of the display. A javascript clock i the lower right corner.

Since a few weeks, I am facing a really strange behaviour:

Sometimes between 06.30 - 06.33 (6.33 AM) every day, something (??) happens and the browser seems to be non responsive on my 7" display. One thing that is strange is that I am able to move the cursor when touching display. Nothing obviously happens when I click on a button, BUT!, since I have started my Chromium instance like this: `chromium-browser --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 --remote-debugging-address==10.0.0.4 --user-data-dir=remote-profile --kiosk http://localhost/kommandoran2.0/#/` (in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`) I am able to remote debug. I can see that correct javascripts are invoked when I click on buttons (in the real world, my switches turns on and off). The problem is that the GUI seems to be semi frozen. At least the GUI in Chrome/KIOSK. The GUI is not updating itself in Chrome

This is the inspector from a Chrome instance on a windows computer in my network when my Pi has been "frozen"
[image]

Ok, some javascript errors, but they are indicating other things.

Since I am the "developer", I am very sure that I have nothing in either backend (node-red) or frontend (VueJS) which should be able to cause this behavior!

Here are some example output from `journalctl` from my Raspberry:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl --since "2019-08-13 06:00:00"        
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[20587]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[20592]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclea
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[20587]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Aug 13 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[24891]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 13 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[24895]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 13 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[24891]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 13 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[29156]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 13 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[29160]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Aug 13 6:25:02      raspberrypi CRON[29156]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: bits received from HRNG source: 260064
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: bits sent to kernel pool: 213824
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: entropy added to kernel pool: 213824
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2 successes: 13
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2 failures: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Monobit: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Poker: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Runs: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Long run: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Continuous run: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: HRNG source speed: (min=422.800; avg=940.174; max=1173.753)Kibits/s
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS tests speed: (min=5.320; avg=9.536; max=16.542)Mibits/s
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: Lowest ready-buffers level: 2
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: Entropy starvations: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: Time spent starving for entropy: (min=0; avg=0.000; max=0)us
******* 06:32 FREEZE
Aug 13 6:34:19      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Aug 13 6:34:23      raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
Aug 13 6:34:23      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Aug 13 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[4436]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 13 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[4442]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean
Aug 13 6:39:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
...

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl --since "2019-08-14 06:00:00"     
Aug 14 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[6668]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi CRON[6674]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi CRON[6668]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Aug 14 6:14:36      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Aug 14 6:14:40      raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 6:14:40      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Aug 14 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[11005]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 14 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[11009]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 14 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[11005]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 14 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[15276]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 14 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[15281]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
Aug 14 6:25:02      raspberrypi CRON[15276]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
******* 06:32 FREEZE        
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[22772]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[22777]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[22772]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
...

******* NOT FREEZING Aug 15     

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl --since "2019-08-16 06:00:00"     
Aug 16 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[13098]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[13102]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]
Aug 16 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[13098]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 6:09:03      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 16 6:09:04      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 16 6:09:04      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Aug 16 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[21638]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[21643]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 16 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[21638]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
******* 06:31 FREEZE        
Aug 16 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[30176]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[30182]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Aug 16 6:25:02      raspberrypi CRON[30176]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[12819]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[12823]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]
Aug 16 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[12819]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 6:39:03      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 16 6:39:04      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 16 6:39:04      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Aug 16 6:41:03      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Aug 16 6:41:06      raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
...
```

I have no problems with power to my Raspberry. I have tried to reinstall the system on a new fresh SD-card. I upgraded from stretch to buster. The problem remains...

This is driving my nuts! I can access my Raspberry Pi via XRDP. Neither the display nor Chromium are completely dead. What is causing the chrome GUI to stop updating? Why is this happening every morning around 06:30 AM??

Answer (score 1):

There might be some cron process scheduled, like the apt repository refresh, or some other scheduled maintenance in the default raspbian configuration (`locate` database update?). A scheduled process could eat up some of the CPU resources leaving chrome less render time.

Have you tried logging the CPU usage in the backgound? There are some good suggestions like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22021/how-to-log-cpu-load
This might help you figure out if something else is happening at the same time on your system.

Unrelated to the main issue, you could also use Chrome debugger to inspect render times of your web app, and make sure you're not wasteful when it comes to rendering the dom and canvas. In case your page uses a meaningful amount of cpu time to render it can make sense that background processes stall it, and optimizing it could help lessen the affect the other processes have on it. Again, I'm not suggesting this is the case, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: Hmmm... Just for trying something new regarding the crons. 'crontab -e' and 'sudo crontab -e' gives me no editable jobs. How would you do if you wanted to disable all cron jobs completely on your pi? (Temporarily of course) Good idea with CPU logging BTW

Comment: I'm not sure if cronjobs are still in use today, I was using the term loosely. I've lost track of all the new service management daemons and I'm almost sure systemd has it's own scheduling service. Also if you're using a desktop environment like xfce it can have it's own auto-startup procedures. That's why I suggested logging first. If you figure out what is eating up the resources it should be easy enough to find what launches it.